# How much does a Formula 1 car really cost?

Tags: finances, formula-1

I have come across several websites claiming that the Formula one car components prices are known and the total price for a car is in the $12-15 million. The websites I'm referring to are like [this one](https://lifebeyondsportmedia.com/The-Average-Cost) and [this one](http://www.tsmplug.com/f1/average-cost-of-formula-1-car/).

Although I know that these prices are not announced and are just estimates, I still felt that there is something wrong and they are just too much no matter how  I look at them. So I kept searching and I came across two more websites [this](https://bleacherreport.com/articles/42136-formula-one-money-money-money-part-3-component-costs) and [this](https://www.f1-grandprix.com/?p=23009). Those two websites alternatively suggest that those prices are actually the whole season running cost for the car. In other words, the engine price is actually 10 times the actual unit price because it is expected to be changed 10 times during the season. The same goes for the other components as well which make the cost of building just one car much less that this $12-15 million figure.

So what do you think? Is my conclusion correct and a single F1 engine does not really cost $7-8 million but actually something like $700-800k?

Comment: "If you have to ask, you can't afford it" :)  Are you taking development costs into account also?  I bet that far exceeds the actual materials+assembly cost.

Comment: Your question makes little sense, not only because there is a difference between "cost" and "price" (you're mixing them along your question), but also because for both terms something has to be sold, and no (current) F1 car is being sold by any team. The only thing being "sold" are the parts, by their suppliers to the teams, and even these are not under normal "retail" rules. You can ask how much a F1 car costs (in the layman terminology) to the teams, but that will imply R&D, among other things. (continue...)

Comment: (continuation) Finally, the power unit (not engine anymore) comparison is also not adequate: for instance, a F1 car has only 4 tyres. So, for calculating how much a F1 car costs, do we add the price of 4 tyres? Or do we calculate the price of 24 tyres, which is the amount a car can use per weekend? As you can see, the fact that a car has only 1 power unit at a time makes little difference for the team/supplier contract. Nowadays they use only 3 PU per season (before penalties), but in the early 80's it was around 200 engines per year (50 new, 150 reconditioned).

Comment: All that being said, the only realistically answerable question would be: *"how much it costs an average team to develop and build a F1 car?"*. That would be the team's budget less drivers and mechanics pay, travel expenses, fuel, tyres, etc., that is, everything not directly related to R&D, build and assembly.

Comment: Once the 2021 regulations come into force, the answer will be $175 million.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for the detailed explanation. What I was actually trying to figure out is the price of the F1 car as the sum of the price of each component that makes the car and not the running cost of the car during a season. I was trying to show that some of the sources that say the cost is $15m or so is actually referring to the running cost and so it adds not only a single item of each component but actually multiple of each. In other words, does it take $15m to supply, manufacture, or purchase 4 tires, 1 PU, 1 monocoque, 1 transmission 1 rear and 1 front wings and so on? or less?

Comment: @AbanobEbrahim it's way more than that, that's my point. Suppose that a given part A costs 10k dollars. However, for developing it, it takes 1 million dollar worth of wind tunnel R&D. So, how much does it costs, actually? 10,000 or 1,010,000?

Comment: Other comparison: when we buy a street car we have to pay the cost of the engineers that developed it, but that cost is diluted in, let's say, 500 thousand units that the company sold. But, for an F1 car, **all** the work of all the engineers must be summed up, because *no unit* is sold. Therefore, my whole tl;dr point: **the cost of an F1 car is not the sum of its parts**. And, again, *cost* here is a inadequate word, technically speaking.